# EditText onSubmit function cleard in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with the recycler view.
If I use the following code, it works perfectly, until I have so many items in my adapter, that it has to scroll a little bit.

the whole project is on [github](https://github.com/cloudsftp/TridomCounter)

```
class ActionCardAdapter(val round: Round, val activity: RoundActivity)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<ActionCardAdapter.AbstractActionCardViewHolder>() {

    abstract class AbstractActionCardViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)

    class ComplexActionCardViewHolder(view: View) : AbstractActionCardViewHolder(view) {
        val actionNameTextView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.actionNameTextView)
        val inputEditText = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.actionInputEditText)

    }

    // other ViewHolders

    enum class ViewType {
        COMPLEX_ACTION_CARD
        // other ViewTypes
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = when (round.cards[position]) {
        is ActionCardComplex -> ViewType.DISPLAY_CARD.ordinal
        // other cases
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, type: Int): AbstractActionCardViewHolder {
        return when (type) {
            ViewType.COMPLEX_ACTION_CARD.ordinal -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.card_action_complex, parent, false) as View

                ComplexActionCardViewHolder(view)

            }

            // other cases

            else -> throw Exception("Card Type not defined.")

        }

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: AbstractActionCardViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val card = round.cards[position]

        when (getItemViewType(position)) {
            ViewType.COMPLEX_ACTION_CARD.ordinal -> {
                viewHolder as ComplexActionCardViewHolder
                card as ActionCardComplex

                viewHolder.actionNameTextView.text = card.displayText

                fun getInput() {
                    // some logic

                }

                viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener { getInput() }
                viewHolder.inputEditText.onSubmit { getInput() }

                viewHolder.inputEditText.requestFocus()

            }



        }

        // other cases

    }

    override fun getItemCount() = round.cards.size

}
```

So if I add one of these ActionCardComplex and like 5 cards that are bound differently,
the onSubmit property of the EditText `viewHolder.inputEditText` seems to be cleared.
The onClickListener of the ItemView `viewHolder.itemView` on the other hand still works.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to incluse the code I use in onSubmit. It is a extension of EditText.
`fun EditText.onSubmit(func: () -> Unit) {
    setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->

        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            func()
        }

        true

    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it by using a different approach to the onSubmit function.
I changed

```
fun EditText.onSubmit(func: () -> Unit) {
    setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->

        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            func()
        }

        true

    }
}
```

to

```
fun EditText.onSubmit(func: () -> Unit) = setOnEditorActionListener {
        _, actionId, _ ->
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT)
            func()

        true

}
```

Because the Keyboard changes it's action button in the bottom right corner to `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT` instead of `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE` when the number of items is so large that they don't fit on the screen.